# Can I excuse my self from all IP rights and say everything belongs to my partner, since my employer "owns all my IP"

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I have signed a contract with my employeer, there is a clause stating they own all my IP in that contract.

When I joined I had spent about 2 years working on a mobile game with some friends. I spent maybe 6-7 months after joining finishing it up.

I am allowed to moonlight. So could I not just say that all work I did on that game after I joined them, was just to help out friend X. I do not own any of it, it's all his?

They have assured me that I don't have to worry unless it competes with their company. But to me that is just empty words since they wont put that in writing (I have an email from HR saying that, since I refused to sign the contract without a written email excemting me from that clause. But not sure if that is enough). If the game were to become successfull, I don't doubt they would try to take it from me if it's "my IP".

Comment: In what jurisdiction are you employed?

Comment: @phoog (Had to sign up to comment), I live in Sweden, employed in Denmark

Comment: I'd keep an archive of that email from HR to be perfectly safe, and also not tell anyone at work that this game is on the market or whether it's successful. They'd be ridiculous to go after you at all, but they can't go after you for what they don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

If, under the agreement, they own the copyright in what you produce then it's not yours to give to anyone.

However, it looks like your company understands the law - they only own 'work product' - that is, stuff developed in their time or that is completely with or competes with their business. If they develop accounting software they have no claim over a game you develop but would have a claim over accounting software - and vice-versa.